# Bootstrap image with only one corner rounded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to make only a single corner rounded with bootstratp?

For example:

> img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre"
>   width="304" height="236"

I am trying to round the top right corner.

This seems to be possible with Jquery, but I am wondering if there is even an easier way.

> jQuery('#flow').corner("TR 15px");

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you just use normal css? `border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px`

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<img id="doge" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000822867536/3f5a00acf72df93528b6bb7cd0a4fd0c.jpeg">
```

**CSS**

```
#doge{
    width:250px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/y0n5upbt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS style `border-top-right-radius: 15px`